# Long term account linking with Google Home

Tags: oauth-2.0, actions-on-google

At the moment I'm using `OAuth and Google Sign-In` for account linking in my app. After this is done an `accessToken` is sent along with the request to my webhook. But the `accessToken` is only valid for a hour. For my Application to work correctly and have a smooth user interaction I don't want my users to link their account every hour. So how do I set up a more permanent account linking process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the details of the OAuth mechanism that you're using with Account Linking.

If you are using the Implicit Flow, then the tokens from your OAuth server are assumed to be good indefinitely.

If you are using the Auth Code Flow, then you should be returning both a short-lived *access token* and a *refresh token* that does not have an expiration. Google will use this *refresh token* to contact your OAuth server when the *access token* has expired to get a new *access token*, which will be sent to your webhook.

If all you need is a single, consistent, identifier that also has some validity outside of the Assistant, you can look into [Google Sign In](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in) (both for apps and websites and for the Assistant). This will give you access to the user's Google ID, with their permission.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but do you have a more detailed explanation about the refresh token and where I can get/generate that token? I'm also trying to experiment with the Google Sign-In and use the IdToken to verify the client, would that be a viable option long term?

Comment: All I need to know is who is sending the request through, I don't need to do anything on their calendar for example. So I don't really need an Access Token all I need to do is verify the user on my server end through the webhook so that I can make a personal response with information saved in our database.

Comment: I can't provide more details about the refresh token, since I don't have any information about your OAuth server. The OAuth server is under your control, and you haven't indicated which auth flow you're using with it, how it is configured, if it is custom built or you're using an outside service, or anything else. You can update your question with this info, and we might be able to provide more info, but it isn't clear what your question would be.

Comment: Using Google Sign In for Assistant *might* be suitable in your case. It depends what you mean by "verify the user on [your] server". You can give it a try and, if you have questions aqbout its use, post another SO question.

Comment: I'm using the Google Sign-In method and it looks like it is what I need, The user links their account with the Assisstant app and every request sends the `conv.user.profile.payload.sub` what I use to index users on our server. Thanks alot for your time and help!